# Teachable Robotic Arm coding error

Tags: c++, arduino, robotics

I am working on a robotic arm that has six servos which is being controlled by an arduino uno. The servos are analog servos from adafruit and they are special in the sense that you can get feedback from the servos, i.e their actual position after you told it where to go. What I am working on is trying to adapt this example code to include six servos instead of one. https://github.com/adafruit/Feedback-Servo-Record-and-Play/blob/master/servo_recordplay.ino

Here is my code so far and its errors

```
// Example code for recording and playing back servo motion with a 
// analog feedback servo
// http://www.adafruit.com/products/1404


#include <Servo.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define CALIB_MAX 512
#define CALIB_MIN 100
#define SAMPLE_DELAY 25 // in ms, 50ms seems good

uint8_t recordButtonPin = 12;
uint8_t playButtonPin = 7;
uint8_t servo1Pin = 9;
uint8_t servo2Pin = 10;
uint8_t servo1FeedbackPin = A0;
uint8_t servo2FeedbackPin = A1;
uint8_t servo3FeedbackPin = A2;
uint8_t servo4FeedbackPin = A3;
uint8_t servo5FeedbackPin = A4;
uint8_t servo6FeedbackPin = A5;
uint8_t ledPin = 13;

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;
Servo servo5;
Servo servo6;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(recordButtonPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(recordButtonPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(playButtonPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(playButtonPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Servo RecordPlay");
}

void loop() {
 if (! digitalRead(recordButtonPin)) {
   delay(10);
   // wait for released
   while (! digitalRead(recordButtonPin));
   delay(20);
   // OK released!
   recordAllServos(servo1Pin, servo1FeedbackPin, recordButtonPin);
 }

  if (! digitalRead(playButtonPin)) {
   delay(10);
   // wait for released
   while (! digitalRead(playButtonPin));
   delay(20);
   // OK released!
   playAllServo(servo1Pin, playButtonPin);
 }
}

void playAllServo(uint8_t servoPin, uint8_t buttonPin) {
  uint16_t addr = 0;
  Serial.println("Playing");


  servo1.attach(servo1Pin);
  while (digitalRead(buttonPin)) {    
    uint8_t x = EEPROM.read(addr);
    Serial.print("Read EE: "); Serial.print(x);
    if (x == 255) break;
    // map to 0-180 degrees
    x = map(x, 0, 254, 0, 180);
    Serial.print(" -> "); Serial.println(x);
    servo1.write(x);
    delay(SAMPLE_DELAY);
    addr++;
    if (addr == 512) break;
  }
  Serial.println("Done");
  servo1.detach();
  delay(250);  
}

void recordAllServos(uint8_t servoPin, uint8_t buttonPin) {
  uint16_t addr = 0;

  Serial.println("Recording");
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

  pinMode(servo1FeedbackPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(servo2FeedbackPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(servo3FeedbackPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(servo4FeedbackPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(servo5FeedbackPin, INPUT); 
  pinMode(servo6FeedbackPin, INPUT); 

  while (digitalRead(buttonPin)) 
  {
     readServo(servo1FeedbackPin);
     readServo(servo2FeedbackPin);
     readServo(servo3FeedbackPin);
     readServo(servo4FeedbackPin);
     readServo(servo5FeedbackPin);
     readServo(servo6FeedbackPin);

     if (addr > 506) break;
     delay(SAMPLE_DELAY);
  }
  if (addr != 1024) EEPROM.write(addr, 255);

  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  Serial.println("Done");
  delay(250);
}

void readAllServo(uint8_t analogPin)
{
     uint16_t a = analogRead(analogPin);

     Serial.print("Read analog pin "); Serial.print(analogPin); Serial.print(": ");
     Serial.print(a);                  
     if (a < CALIB_MIN) a = CALIB_MIN;
     if (a > CALIB_MAX) a = CALIB_MAX;
     a = map(a, CALIB_MIN, CALIB_MAX, 0, 254);
     Serial.print(" -> "); Serial.println(a);
     EEPROM.write(addr, a);
     addr++;
}
```

The errors that I am getting from the arduino ide are

```
Teachable_Arm_Mark.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
Teachable_Arm_Mark:10: error: too many arguments to function 'void recordAllServos(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
Teachable_Arm_Mark:49: error: at this point in file
Teachable_Arm_Mark.cpp: In function 'void recordAllServos(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
Teachable_Arm_Mark:100: error: 'readServo' was not declared in this scope
Teachable_Arm_Mark.cpp: In function 'void readAllServo(uint8_t)':
Teachable_Arm_Mark:127: error: 'addr' was not declared in this scope
```

Any help much appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Good question. Try to add what you have done to fixed these problems nad how what you did affected it.

Answer (score 0):

In void loop you have

```
  recordAllServos(servo1Pin, servo1FeedbackPin, recordButtonPin);
```

but recordAllServos is declared as

```
void recordAllServos(uint8_t servoPin, uint8_t buttonPin)
```

Hence too many arguments 3 vs 2...

Comment: Thank you I made that change.